# Mark form as dirty on redirect in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-admin

I am writing a DuplicateButton component for the RA's `<Datagrid>` that just takes the current record and passes the data as the state to the create form on click:

```js
/* redirectTo: RedirectionSideEffect,
   resource: string = '',
   id?: Identifier,
   data?: Partial<RaRecord>,
   state: object = {}
*/
redirect('create', resource, undefined, {}, { record: data });
```

It works fine but when the form is opened, despite it having all the data, the save button is disabled and I can't instantly hit save to quickly duplicate the record (making it impossible to create exactly the same record). Is there a hidden property to pass to make the form dirty right away?

I could technically write my own toolbar with a `SaveButton` that checks for redirects but that would require me to go over every form I have in the app which is not ideal.

Comment: React-Admin already has a CloneButton: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CloneButton.html

Comment: @MaxAlex my record requires some transformations before passing it to the form which is why I opted for a custom one.

Comment: Found a mini-hack myself after some research - `<SaveButton>` has an `alwaysEnable` prop. With some bandaids it can be utilized to enable the button.